# efficacy vs. efficiency

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I've got troubles perceiving the difference in meaning between these terms. They have different *Latin roots* which means they have to be different (efficacy—*efficacia*, efficiency—*efficientia*). These nouns also have different derived adjectives (efficacy—*efficacious*, efficiency—*efficient*).

I will try to swap these terms and you say whether the sentences sound correct?

> There is little information on the **efficiency** of this treatment.
>
> Greater energy **efficacy**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Efficacy** refers to the *effectiveness*  of a body or a system. Whether is has the capacity or power to produce the desired result.

**Efficiency** on the contrary is the ratio of output to the input of any system. In other terms how well has something been done.